# Netbeans : uploading files from project sub directory to server root

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using netbeans 8 to work on a PHP project.

I would like to have project tree like this :

```
My Project
|---Source Files //netbeans' logical directory
    |--- src //contains all the files I want to upload on remote server
    |--- test //some tests based on src
    |--- extra //other files like readme, samples, etc...
    |--- build.xml //ant
```

My problem is I don't know how to configure netbeans so it uploads only the files under src/* to webroot (and not webroot/src/*) and still show the other files in editor

(I've tried the configurate the project properties -> sources / run configuration but i haven't succeeded to match src with webroot).

Comment: I've struggled with this many times. My conclusion is that it cannot be done.

Comment: There's even a [third-party plug-in](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39197/ftpsitedeployer) that apparently inherits this same limitation.

Comment: The only way that I've managed to do this is to use the 'src' folder as the project root. I then have chosen to either add a new "parent" project that includes everything which I can edit without worrying about uploading, or use the command line to run version control. That's depending on the size of the project, of course.